# How to make the keyboard work as a touchscreen in Python?

Tags: python, winapi, keyboard, mouseevent, pyautogui

If `LtRt()` executed 1st `UpDown()` doesnt work and vice-versa. What should I do? Also please help me optimize the code.
I play games from an app that doesnt support to login via Android emulator like Bluestacks etc. Because they autofill the security code, which emulators cant fill. In PC I can't play these games with the mouse as I need fingers touch (better flexibility)

Is it possible to make my keyboard work like fingers on a touchscreen on PC?

For example:

```py
'w' = front 
'q' = top left corner
'e' = top right corner
'a' = left
's' = presses or at center 
'd' = right
'z' = bottom left corner 
'x' = back 
'c' = bottom right corner
```

Is there any way to directly command Windows to make 9 points and tap?
And if <kbd>s</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> are pressed give a swipe to the right (as if with a finger) and so on?

```py
import win32api
from time import sleep
import keyboard as kb
import sys
import pyautogui as pg

def UpDown():
    py = (win32api.GetCursorPos())[1]
    y = py
    while True:
        px = (win32api.GetCursorPos())[0]
        x = px
        #TOP
        if kb.is_pressed('w'):
            # win32api.SetCursorPos((y,574))
            pg.moveTo(x, y, duration=0.0)
            y = y - 40
        #BOTTOM
        if kb.is_pressed('s'):
            # win32api.SetCursorPos((y,574))
            pg.moveTo(x, y, duration=0.0)
            y = y + 40
        # Y = NEW POSITION; ON RELEASE
        if not kb.is_pressed('w') and not kb.is_pressed('s'):
            y = (win32api.GetCursorPos())[1]

def LtRt():
    px = (win32api.GetCursorPos())[0]
    x = px
    while True:
        py = (win32api.GetCursorPos())[1]
        y = py
        # X = NEW POSITION; ON RELEASE
        if not kb.is_pressed('a') and not kb.is_pressed('d'):
            x = (win32api.GetCursorPos())[0]
        #LEFT
        if kb.is_pressed('a'):
            # win32api.SetCursorPos((y,574))
            pg.moveTo(x, y, duration=0.0)
            x = x - 60
        #RIGHT
        if kb.is_pressed('d'):
            # win32api.SetCursorPos((y,574))
            pg.moveTo(x, y, duration=0.0)
            x = x + 60

if __name__ == "__main__":
    LtRt()
    UpDown()
    while kb.is_pressed('q'):
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

I somehow managed an answer of my own problem (^_^)!

> called the same function **win32api.GetCursorPos()** in 2 way and called them in 2 way.
> But Someone to help me with an OPTIMIZED version of this. Thanks in Advance from all who will be getting help from this in future...

```
import win32api
from time import sleep
import keyboard as kb
import sys
import pyautogui as pg


def UpDown():
    #UpDown > qy
    qy = (win32api.GetCursorPos())[1]
    y = qy
    #LtRt > x1 y1
    px = (win32api.GetCursorPos())[0]
    x1 = px
    while True:
        #UpDown
        px = (win32api.GetCursorPos())[0]
        x = px
        #LtRt
        py = (win32api.GetCursorPos())[1]
        y1 = py
        #TOP
        if kb.is_pressed('w'):
            # win32api.SetCursorPos((y,574))
            pg.moveTo(x, y, duration=0.0)
            y = y - 40
        #BOTTOM
        if kb.is_pressed('s'):
            # win32api.SetCursorPos((y,574))
            pg.moveTo(x, y, duration=0.0)
            y = y + 40
        # Y = NEW POSITION; ON RELEASE
        if not kb.is_pressed('w') and not kb.is_pressed('s'):
            y = (win32api.GetCursorPos())[1]


        # X = NEW POSITION; ON RELEASE
        if not kb.is_pressed('a') and not kb.is_pressed('d'):
            x1 = (win32api.GetCursorPos())[0]
        #LEFT
        if kb.is_pressed('a'):
            # win32api.SetCursorPos((y,574))
            pg.moveTo(x1, y1, duration=0.0)
            x1 = x1 - 60
        #RIGHT
        if kb.is_pressed('d'):
            # win32api.SetCursorPos((y,574))
            pg.moveTo(x1, y1, duration=0.0)
            x1 = x1 + 60

        if kb.is_pressed('q'):
            break


UpDown()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).